# Meteor.call losing session in IE 10

Tags: meteor, internet-explorer-10

When running the following code:

```
Meteor.call('updateRubricStudentAssessments', ids, setVal, function (err, updateCount) {
                console.log(Session.get("selected_classroom"));
                saveAssessmentDataCallback(ids);
            });
```

the `selected_classroom` session variable is output as `undefined` in IE 10 but in Firefox, Chrome and Safari the data in the `session` is present. Is this a known bug in IE 10 or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm trying to do a `Meteor.call()` on IE9 and it's also not working.